# LockService does not prevent concurrent script runs when paired with inputBox

Tags: google-apps-script, locking

So I think I have found an issue with the locking system. That is, when you trigger a popup box(that appears within a specified sheet) in the script, it scraps the lock... Or something like that, because it definitely doesn't keep the lock.

I have a segment of code I am trying to run and basically without the popup, the locking system works. There is no issue, the haslock will indeed return false when the first user has the lock, but then you introduce a popup box and the locking system doesn't work like it should, and grants a lock to the 2nd user even tho the popup box and that line of code, or any lines of code after it for that matter, have not been executed..

I tried it with a delay after the popup box because I originally thought that maybe it's not waiting for the input back so therefore it just kinda skips over the popup box after it has pushed it out to the sheet... but even with a long delay after the popup box portion of the code the 2nd user is still granted a lock.. Maybe I am doing this wrong but the popup box is the only thing that throws my code off.

I tried the `try...catch`, I found an equivalent `if...else if` and no luck, i even tried just an `if...else`... I know it is not because the `trylock` is too long, or too short I've tried a range of values, I also know it is not the `sleep` because I've tried a range of values, as well as different placements within my code.

Tested these quite heavily, on different google user accounts on multiple different days bc I originally thought it was me just being dumb or something, but it really just seems like the popup box is the only thing that sends it off the reservation.

**Examples of when the locking system works**

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  if (!lock.hasLock()) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
    return;
  }
  else if (lock.hasLock()) {
    Logger.log('got the lock');
    //Browser.inputBox("TESTING123");
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
lock.releaseLock();
}
```

2

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  if (!lock.hasLock()) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('got the lock');
    //Browser.inputBox("TESTING123");
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
lock.releaseLock();
}
```

with the proposed try,catch statement

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(5000); // wait 5 seconds try to get lock
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  //Browser.inputBox("TESTING123");
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

it does indeed catch the error and display the popup saying it couldn't get it

**Examples when it doesn't work**

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  if (!lock.hasLock()) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
    return;
  }
  else if (lock.hasLock()) {
    Logger.log('got the lock');
    Browser.inputBox("TESTING123");
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
 lock.releaseLock();
}
```

2

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  if (!lock.hasLock()) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('got the lock');
    Browser.inputBox("TESTING123");
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
lock.releaseLock();
}
```

with the proposed try catch statement

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(5000); // wait 5 seconds try to get lock
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  Browser.inputBox("TESTING123");
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

the popup box appears in all cases. It shouldn't, because the popup box hasn't been filled in and resolved... even with putting a delay after the popup box line. I have decided to take to making my own locking system as it doesn't seem that the google system will be working for me since I need the lock to remain valid after popups.

@OlegValter not a worry with prompt, if users don't input info into the popup boxes as of the testing I've currently done it errors out and then doesn't input anything into the sheet anyways. I have come up with a work around for lock using properties service(thank you again)

```
function myFunction() {
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const lock = properties.getProperty('Lock');
  Logger.log(lock);
  //if no one else has the lock
  if(lock == null){
    //set the value of the kvp to locked
    properties.setProperty('Lock', 'Locked');
    Logger.log('got the lock');
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
  }
  else{
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock');
    return;
  }
  //after we have ran the body of the code we want to delete the KVP bc we want the script to be open to other users
  properties.deleteProperty('Lock');
}
```

I am currently using ScriptProperties for now as I have different users running the same script. I am finalizing most of the backend functionality for the infrastructure I have built. I plan to do some sort of app control. Ex: I want my users to basically click on a link, or open up an app on their phone that will take them to a UI that will run some of these updates, instead of needing to have every user have a google account. Any recommendations with what to go thru for UI, app control, or website.. really not sure what direction would be best at the moment I plan to feel things out.

Thank you again for your help, tried to format things a bit better this time around.

Comment: If you think it's a real issue then report it. [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B)

Comment: `Lock`s are not persisted across dialogs - if you need a workaround, see above for an emulator that uses `PropertiesService` under the hood. Also please do not use `inputBox`, it is not recommended, use [`prompt`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) instead. Finally, please, going forward, split the introductory block of text in the question into paragraphs, a single block is very hard to read through (also please use Ctrl+K for small code blocks)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Oleg, I will further look into PropertiesService to see if that will suffice. Also I wasn't aware of popup box vs prompt so thank you for leading me onto something there. Apologies for the poor formatting I was just trying to spill it all out.

Comment: @keithwalker - don't mention, hope this is what you need, it is the only viable workaround I can think of. Re:prompt - please be mindful about execution time, as if the user leaves the screen open long enough, the script may timeout. Re:formatting - no worries, but do try to follow the guidelines, otherwise questions tend to get downvoted or, worse, in case of mistagging, skipped over completely

Comment: @OlegValter I believe I found a workaround with properties service from the testing I've done so far it is indeed working how I want it to. Added this in the original post. Thanks again

Comment: Instead of editing your question, consider adding a answer to the linked duplicate question.

Comment: @TheMaster - the problem is that the solution is absolutely identical to the original :) But yes, please do not edit the question to include answers there - either answer the dupe target or move on, glad you resolved it, keith walker!